# Performance of the 'ImmutableSortedSet.IsSubsetOf' method

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, immutability

I'm just wondering about the performance of the ImmutableSortedSet.IsSubsetOf method ( the source is  https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Collections.Immutable/src/System/Collections/Immutable/ImmutableSortedSet_1.cs ).

In the original implementation we have this code:

```
public bool IsSubsetOf(IEnumerable<T> other)
        {
            Requires.NotNull(other, nameof(other));

            if (this.IsEmpty)
            {
                return true;
            }

            //...comments...
            var otherSet = new SortedSet<T>(other, this.KeyComparer);
            int matches = 0;
            foreach (T item in otherSet)
            {
                if (this.Contains(item))
                {
                    matches++;
                }
            }

            return matches == this.Count;
}
```

We iterate over the 'otherSet' and for each item we try to find it in the original sorted set. It takes us O(m log(n)) time where 'm' is the size of 'otherSet' and 'n' is the size of the original sorted set.

But we have two sorted sets. We can just use the same approach as we use in the 'merge sort' algorithm. I mean this method can be implemented the following way (it's just a prototype, not a code for production):

```
bool IsSubsetOf<T>(IEnumerable<T> other)
    {
        if (this.IsEmpty)
        {
            return true;
        }

        var otherSet = new SortedSet<T>(other, this.KeyComparer);
        int matches = 0;

        var otherEnumerator = otherSet.GetEnumerator();
        var thisEnumerator = this.GetEnumerator();

        bool isEndOfThis = !thisEnumerator.MoveNext();
        bool isEndOfOther = !otherEnumerator.MoveNext();
        while (!isEndOfThis && !isEndOfOther)
        {
            int comparisonResult = this.KeyComparer.Compare(otherEnumerator.Current, thisEnumerator.Current);

            //we have a hit. let's move both iterators.
            if (comparisonResult == 0)
            {
                matches++;
                isEndOfThis = !thisEnumerator.MoveNext();
                isEndOfOther = !otherEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            //setEnumerator.Current is more than otherSetEnumerator.Current. 
            else if (comparisonResult < 0)
            {                    
                isEndOfOther = !otherEnumerator.MoveNext();
            }
            //setEnumerator.Current is less than otherSetEnumerator.Current. 
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return matches == this.Count;
    }
```

This implementation takes us O(r) time where 'r'=max('n','m').

So, my question is 'Why the original implementation doesn't use the approach which I described?'.

Comment: Possibly due to time constraints. Or maybe this algorithm on general doesn't hit its worst case often. But the great news is, is that if you're confident that your version is better in all circumstances you can make a pull request and it might be implemented in the next version of .net :).

Comment: What's the complexity of `new SortedSet<T>(other, this.KeyComparer)`?

Comment: The complexity of 'new SortedSet<T>(other, this.KeyComparer)' is O(n log(n)) because inside of this constructor we create AVL tree.